# cannot add table borders in jupyter notebook markdown cell

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get solid black table borders on my html table in jupyter notebook. I run the following code in a markdown cell:

```
<table {style="border-style: solid;"}>
    <tr>
        <td>parameter
        </td>
        <td>eenheid
        </td>
        <td>waarde
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>$RR$
        </td>
        <td>$\text{[-]}$
        </td>
        <td>0.03
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But now I would like all cells in the table (all td and tr elements) to have their own border. Is there really no other way to do this than adding a `{style="border-style: solid;"}` to each td and tr element?

Adding table borders is really basic functionality. It shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other way. But a hack is: adding replace after HTML string.

```
html_string.replace("<td>", "<td style='border-style: solid;'>")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way (in a CSS file or  tag):

```css
table tr {
 border-style: solid;
}
table tr td {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: If you paste that in a markdown cell in jupyter notebook you'll see that it doesn't work.